# Application of Stone-Weierstrass with a non-unital algebra

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. We say that a function $f\colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ vanishes at $\infty$ if for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists a compact $K_\epsilon \subset X$ such that   $|f(x)|< \epsilon, \forall x\in X-K_\epsilon$.
>
> We denote by $C_0(X)$ the set of all such functions and we endow it with the usual operations of addition and multiplication of functions, and multiplication of functions by scalars.
>
> (i) Show that one has a well-defined norm
>
> $\left|\left|\cdot\right|\right|:C_0(X) \to \mathbb{R}, f\to 
> ||f||:=\sup\left\{ {|f(x)|:x \in X}\right\}$
>
> and together with this norm, $C_0(X)$ becomes a Banach space.
>
> (ii) Assume that $\mathbb{A}\subset C_0(X)$ has the following properties:
>
> 1. $\mathbb{A}$ is a non-unital subalgebra of $C_0(X)$.
> 2. $\mathbb{A}$ is strongly point-separating: it is point separating and, $\forall x \in X$, there exists $f\in \mathbb{A}$ such that $f(x)\neq0$.
>
> Show that $\mathbb{A}$ is dense in $C_0(X)$.

(i) was easy, but I'm completely stumped on (ii). Since Stone Weierstrass requires an unital subalgebra in a nontrivial way I don't know how to proceed. Due the way the question is phrased and the conditions given, it is very suggestive of using one-point compactification and then either producing a unit (which doesn't work as far as I can see) or proceeding in an entirely different way. I'd very much appreciate a hint.

Please note that this is not homework.

EDIT: I've found the solution.

**Proof.** $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space and so can be one-point compactified. We do so and obtain $X^*$. We imbed $A$ into $C(X^*)$, using the fact that any element $a$ of $A$ vanishes at the extra point $\infty$. Send that  $a$ to the $b\in C(X^*)$ that is is equal to $a$ for all point in $X$ and zero at $\infty$. This defines $A^*$, a subalgebra of $C(X^*)$. Similarly we can imbed $C_0(X)$ into $C_0(X^*)$. This obviously respects the norm. Moreover we define $B^*:=$Span$(A^*)\cup \left\{{1}\right\}$. $B^*$ is a point separating unital subalgebra of $C(X^*)$, because $A$ is strongly point separating. We now apply Stone-Weierstrass and the fact that $X^*$ is compact Hausdorff to find that $B^*$ is dense in $C(X^*)$.

Observe that the closure of $A^*$ lies in $C(X^*)\cap $Cl$(B^*)$, because $C(X^*)\cap $Cl$(B^*)$ is closed and and contains $A^*$. Let $\gamma \in C_0(X^*)=C(X^*)\cap $Cl$(B^*)$. $\gamma$ lies in $C_0(X^*)$, so $\gamma$ is zero at $\infty$, and it is a limit point of $B$. Note however that every sequence to $\gamma$ lies in $A^*$ after a certain index. So the $\gamma$ is in the closure of $A^*$. As noted earlier, bijection between $A$ and $A^*$ respects the norm. It follows that $A$ lies dense in $C_0(X)$.

Comment: $B^\ast$ isn't a subalgebra since it isn't closed under addition. You want the subalgebra $A^\ast\oplus \mathbb{C}1$.

Comment: Furthermore: The claim that every sequence converging to some $\gamma\in C_0(X)$ must lie in $C_0(X)$ after some finite index is also wrong. This is equivalent to the claim that every sequence of complex numbers (specifically the sequence $\gamma_n(\infty)$) which converges to zero is zero after some finite index which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\tilde{X}$ be the one-point compactification of $X$,  embed the linear span of $A$ and constants in $C(\tilde{X})$, and use the ordinary Stone-Weierstrass theorem there.

Comment: I don't quite follow. How can one use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem without a unital algebra?

Comment: That's what the constants are for.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but this isn't clear to me at all. I can see that embedding the linear span of $A$ and the constants will produce a suitable algebra that lies dense in $C(X*)$. But how does it follow that $A$ lies dense in $C_0(X)$? Thanks for your help!

Comment: $C_0(X)$ is the null space of a continuous linear functional.  The intersection of that with the span of $A$ and the constants is $A$.

Comment: For $\epsilon>0$ and $F\in C_0(X)$, we know there exist $g=f+c$ that is within $\epsilon/2$ of $F$ where $f\in A$ and $c$ a constant (by the above answer). It's easy to see that $c$ must be less than $\epsilon/2$ (look at what happens at infinity). Finally, using the triangle inequality we can see that $\|F-f\|\leq \|F-g\|+\|g-f\|<\epsilon$.